# Does while (reader.Read()) automatically close itself?

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

Usually when I am coding in C# I either write my `SqlDataReader` one of two ways:

```
reader.Read();

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    // Code here
}

reader.Close();
```

Or:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    // Code here
}
```

In the first instance I open the `SqlDataReader` and close it. The second one I am just called `reader.Read()` in a while loop.

My question is: Does calling `reader.Read()` close itself after it has read all data? Or should I still call `reader.Close()`?

Comment: _Hopefully_ you've got it all wrapped up in a `using` block, which will close it and clean up anything left over too.

Comment: Yes. I always use usings. Just didn't know if that would clean it up or if I should still manually close them out.

Comment: Fyi, you can use `reader.HasRows` before you call `Read`. You don't need to advance the reader to the next record to know if it contains rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or:

```
using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

...which calls `IDisposable.Dispose` if assigned object inside the using statement is an `IDisposable` when the `using` block ends (if it's not an `IDisposable` compiler will cry!), which is a syntactic sugar of:

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

try
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Code here
    }
}
finally
{
    if(reader != null)
    {
        reader.Dispose();
    }
}
```

You can either call `Close` or `Dispose`, but use the `using` approach always in order to avoid leaving a disposable object *non disposed* if an exception is thrown before the `Close` or `Dispose` is called.

### Update...

As some commenter has said, `using` block is also for who's vague and this way it's not possible that you forgot to call `Dispose` as it's implicitly-called.

BTW, this is subjective because who misses a `Dispose` call probably won't use `using` block... From my experience, there're still a lot of .NET developers who don't understand the importance of *why an object implement `IDisposable`*.

It's not just a cosmetic detail: if a type implements `IDisposable` is because it is mandatory to call `Dispose` either when you instantiate the `IDisposable` type and you don't need it anymore or during a specific moment in the application life-cycle. **But either way, the `IDisposable.Dispose` call is mandatory**.

My two cents about the topic will be that `using` block is a good way of not having to explain low-level details to unexperienced .NET developers. It's easier to define a team development rule / guide where you may state that **code review won't pass if a `IDisposable` object isn't instantiated within an `using` block without a clear justification**.

Comment: It is a compile time error to assign an object which does not implement ```IDisposable```. Also the using statement is not just about handling exceptions it makes your code more maintainable because you cannot forget to ```Dispose``` on the resource.

Comment: @AluanHaddad That's exactly why you use `using` or `try/finally`. Because you want to call `Dispose` in any case. Right, you can be vague and miss a `Dispose` call, but after all, the main issue to solve is *what happens if something goes wrong during the using block code*. You want to call `Dispose` if it throws an exception to be sure that no resources aren't released and then, never reclaimed by the GC, and what's worse: **a possible deadlock depending on what should be disposed**

Comment: Well I downvoted because your statement reads "which automatically calls IDisposable.Dispose if assigned object inside the using statement is an IDisposable" which will probably confuse someone who is not even familiar with the using statement. It should be reworded.

Comment: @AluanHaddad From the high-level language point of view, it does this. This Q&A isn't about C# compiler...

Comment: @AluanHaddad I've "re-worded" it. Maybe you're right that some unexperienced developers might feel there's magic while it's just a syntactic sugar.

Comment: I've removed the downvote but I think you are missing my point. Its just a question of being precise. If the type doesn't implement IDisposable it is a compile time error to assign it to the resource variable declared in the using block. I agree with your closing statement that a clear justification would indeed be required to deviate from the using statement convention.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I know. BTW, I don't understand the part of "it is a compile time error". Yes, you can only provide `IDisposable` objects. But if the object isn't `IDisposable`, I don't understand how it relates to this topic :D

Answer (score 6):

> Does calling reader.Read() close itself after it has read all data?

No. [`Read()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) just moves cursor to the next row. The default position is *before* the first record. That's why you *have to* use this method to read any data in your reader.

> should I still call a reader.Close();

Yes but instead of that, use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlDataReader` automatically.

```
using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
     while (reader.Read())
     {
         // Code here
     }
} <-- your reader will be disposed here.
```

Comment: This is the best answer and I upvoted, but there is no need for the ```HasRows``` guard around the while loop. The while loop on its own is clean and idiomatic and accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Oh yes, deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

No, [`Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx) will not close it, nor will any other method do that without you telling it to do so. So you will have to close it directly all the time.

However, since [`SqlDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) implements [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx), you should just wrap your reader in a `using` block:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = GetReaderFromSomewhere())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

Then you don’t need to worry about closing it manually, and it will be automatically closed as soon as you leave the `using` block.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will remain open until the GC cleans it up, which may or may not happen right away, or at all.

you should probably go with something like:

```
using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(reader.Read())
    {
         //do stuff with row
    }
}
```

as the reader will be disposed after exiting the using and will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not close your dataReader. When you dispose the object, then yes, it will close. As a good pratice and since your type implement the `IDisposable`, prefer using the [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/yh598w02.aspx) keyword.

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
      // ....
    }
}
```

It will close the reader for you implicity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to close the connection.

SqlDataReader is IDisposable so the safest way to use it if you can is in a using statment:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = GetSqlDataReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. [SqlDataReader](http://SqlDataReader) implements [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to release unmanaged resources - the easiest way to code this is to wrap your usage of the reader inside a [using block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx):

```
using (var reader = getYourReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
         // work is done here
    }
} // leaving the using block reader.Dispose() will be called automatically
```